Words of "spirit and life" & The Flesh is of No Help? - Understanding Jesus' Message (John 6:61-65)
I hope this question is acceptable on here. (I've had an awful experience with StackExchange in the past -- specifically on MathSE -- so I'm a little anxious typing all of this. Please just comment if I need to adjust something or change my post, I will very gladly oblige.) There's a section in the Book of John which I've been pondering on and researching about for a far large amount of time than I am willing to admit. It reads as follows:

(John 6:61-65, ESV) "But Jesus, knowing in himself that his disciples were grumbling about this, said to them, 'Do you take offense to this? Then what if you were to see the Son of Man ascending to where he was before? (1) It is the Spirit who gives life; (2) the flesh is no help at all. The words I have spoken to you are (3) spirit and life. But there are some of you who do not (4) believe...(5) This is why I told you that no one can come to me unless it is granted him by the father.'"


It is the Spirit who gives life. To preface, I am very new to scripture and Christian doctrine. And so far, this book doesn't feel the most beginner friendly, as demonstrated by the following question: Is Jesus saying here that it is the Holy Spirit which gives life? (Or is this an obvious fact I should already know about?) The capitalization of "S" in "Spirit" and the "who" leads me to believe this "Spirit" entity which Jesus is talking about must be a "who" of great importance; hence, the Holy Spirit. However, given how out-of-place such a remark reads (to me), I'm curious if it's possible Jesus is speaking in two-ways here: That is, "Spirit" refers to both the Holy Spirit and lowercase "spirit" (whatever this might be...).

The flesh is no help at all. From what I have read, Jesus is stating that either (i) to "eat [Jesus'] flesh" shouldn't be taken literally, or (ii) no amount of human effort will lead to "life".

The words I have spoken to you are spirit and life. What exactly does Jesus mean by "spirit and life" here? That is, how is Jesus defining the classification of "words" which are of "spirit and life"? I recall this similar classification coming up when Jesus was chatting with the Samaritan woman (John 3), where he expresses that followers of Jesus must worship in "truth and spirit" (or something along these lines).

This is why I told you that no one can come to me unless it is granted him by the Father. My understanding of this verse: Because there exists somebody (i.e. Judas) doesn't "believe" in Jesus authority, it holds that "no one can come to [Jesus] unless it is granted him by the Father"? Is this a correct interpretation?


I pray that the Father may bless me with His true wisdom in your responses. Any help is immensely helpful. Thank you.

Yes, those 5 verses are very deep, so that anyone beginning to read the New Testament with John's gospel is really jumping in at the deep end. The first few verses in chapter 1 would have to be grasped first before what follows appears clearly.
You ask about the Spirit who gives life, the flesh being no help, the words of Jesus being 'spirit and life', and no-one coming to Christ Jesus unless the Father enables that to happen. The way this site works, it would be better to ask four separate questions. Or, perhaps, two sets of double-questions: The Spirit and the spirit, then only the Father enabling coming to Christ, not the flesh. Just a suggestion.
However, a brief answer can still be given. The Holy Spirit leads and guides into "all truth", Jesus said to his followers (John 17:13-15 & 15:26-27). His role is to testify of Christ, and he began his special work at Pentecost, after the risen Christ had ascended to where he was before. Then the 'called-out-ones' (ecclesia in Greek = the congregation Christ said he would build, that the gates of hell would never overcome) burst onto the world's scene. Jesus is speaking exclusively here of the Holy Spirit.
The 'other' spirit in lower-case 's' refers to the words of life Jesus utters, which are spirit, and which are life. This is spiritual life he speaks of, eternal life in him, when he is believed and obeyed in faith. In his pre-incarnate state, Jesus is called the Word of God - John 1:1-4. In him is life. His words are truth, and they are life to those who believe them. In John chapter 4 he tells the Samaritan woman that the Father is "looking for those who will worship him in spirit and in truth" (vss. 23 & 24). When we go to Jesus for those words of life and truth, we are being drawn to the Son by the Father.
Jesus states that "the flesh" is no help at all in seeking for this everlasting life he gives (John 17:2-3). This is a spiritual quest that the Holy Spirit is powerfully involved in. No man-made, human efforts will help. Rather, they will hinder. Indeed, without the Father's enabling, no-one can come to saving faith in Jesus. The Holy Spirit is sent to gather those "called-out-ones" to form this living 'church' or, better, gathering of believers.
This is only a sketch of an answer, for to do justice to all four points raised would take a huge amount of text. Let me just conclude with this quotation from a book dealing with those 5 verses in John's gospel:

"Unless the apostolic preaching of the evangel were believed, since
this is the witness of God, it is certain that those who disbelieved neither 'ate of the flesh' nor 'drank of the blood' of the Son of man,
neither had they eternal lie.
Whence it follows that without the preaching of the cross of Christ
'evidently set forth crucified among you'; of the doctrine of Christ
opening the cause of his flesh being hung on the tree, and the
truth of the shedding of his blood there can be neither 'eating' nor 'drinking'.
For faith cometh by hearing, and through belief union and communion is
brought to pass inwardly and spiritually. Then eternal lie must
follow."  John Chapters 1 to 12 - The first six signs, pp. 296-297,
John Metcalfe
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm


This is a very helpful response! Thank you for sharing. It was certainly a very loaded question, but this feels sufficient according for the "constraints" of this site.
